# How to fetch standby hostname from primary host

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration

I'm in a situation where i need to get the hostname of standby server from my primary host.
the usual way would be by using the alias name. but in some cases the alias name of standby is set to scan rather than hostname in log_archive_dest. so we're unable to get the standby details.

any alternate would be really grateful :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a script for sqlplus.
In the script, you first get the `tns_alias` standby bd from the `log_archive_dest` parameter.
Then connect to standby bd  as sysdba.

```
sqlplus sys/password@tns_alias as sysdba
```

and run SQL

```
select host_name  from  v$instance
```

**Uodate 1**
You can run the query on the main server and see the active sessions from the standby server.

```
    select  machine,program
    from v$session
    where username='PUBLIC' 
    and osuser='oracle'
    and machine <>'db-01.domen'

    MACHINE                                PROGRAM                                                
    ----------------------------- ------------------------------------                                        
db-02.domen    oracle@db-02.domen (TNS V1-V3)
```

Comment: how do we get the sys password for standy node from primarynode?
Thank you :)

Comment: Usually they are the same on the main and standby.

Comment: Hi Dimity thank you so much for your response. It is working fine as expected.
just a small query,
v$session should return only primary sessions right ?
or am i missing something here.?
We get the required result by just using select machine,program from v$session where username='PUBLIC' and osuser='oracle_instance_name';

can you please tell me "machine <>'db-01.domen'" used for ?
Thank you so much

Comment: In this example, db-01 primary database, db-02 standby, standby connect to the primary and receives data on archival logs and log switches, if the condition <> db-01 remove , then we get the system processes of the database primary

Comment: Are there any alternative methods for Exadata servers?

The servers are running on infiniBand connection
sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL> select machine from v$session where username='PUBLIC';

no rows selected

SQL>

Comment: @Dmity: We tried it with gv$session over v$session, it worked :)